# Native packaging for JavaFX 8 Maven project, how to

Tags: maven, deployment, javafx, javafx-8

I can make native installer for my JavaFX 8 application (.msi with WiX) through Netbeans for an ANT project, but how can i create a native installer .msi or .exe (Inno) for a Maven project?

Generally i just want to deploy my application for the enduser with installer now...

With http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-bundle.html i get error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:jar (jar) on
project MyProject: Execution jar of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:ja
r failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.zenjava:jav
afx-maven-plugin:2.0:jar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.tools.pack
ager.Log.setLogger(Lcom/sun/javafx/tools/packager/Log$Logger;)
```

For that i tried Maven versions 3.0.5, 3.1.1 and 3.2.5, so this "API Incompatibility" then i guess is not about Maven version. That plugin is also from 2013 so might need a new one but i don't know any alternatives.

excerp from POM.XML where ZenJava plugin:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.company.Hello</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Any particular reasons for still using `v2.0` of the plugin?

Comment: ITachiUchiha is right, the OP is probably using v2.0 because their site is still mentioning v2.0 of their plugin as of this date ([see here](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/basic-config.html)). The latest version ([search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.zenjava)) is 8.1.2!

Comment: Omg! That's it! There is no particural reason for any version, i thought that to be latest, didn't check maven central. Works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 2):

The `com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin` version that you use must be in sync with the javaFX version. 
This means if you use java 7 with javaFX2 u need to use `v2.0` of the plugin. If you use java 8 before `8u20` u need to use `v8.1.0` and from `8u20` u need to use `v8.1.2`.